# where can i download mxquery-android.jar from?

Tags: android

I would like to download mxquery for android - the jar that contains the package "ch.ethz.mxquery.android.MXQueryService" and other android packages. I tried but the links within mxquery.org do not work. mxquery.org does have mxquery.jar which is the regular jar and does not contain android specific packages. mxquery.org also contains the raw source code which can be built to create the jar, but i am looking for jar only and don't want to build it on my computer.

Can someone point me in the right direction or send me the jar? i am trying to develop an android app that uses mxquery and plan to copy this jar into the "libs" directory

Answer (score 0):

From what can be discerned from the [MXQuery website](http://mxquery.org/), it appears that this project has been abandoned. The first public version of XQuery on Android was published July 7th, 2011 and there does not seem to be any update in the four years or so since.